# Logstash parse kv fields with keys that have spaces in them

Tags: logstash

I have the following kv from a 3rd party...

```
id:636B6130 sub:000 dlvrd:000 submit date:1711121607 done date:1711121607 stat:DELIVRD err:0 text:
```

The only way I see to parse this is to gsub submit date and done date to submit_date and done_date respectively and then apply kv.

Any other way or is that good enough?

Comment: I would say it's good enough, I don't see any simpler solution.